# Error when compiling for MicroChip 'invalid operands to binary =='

Tags: c, struct

```
static int handle_put_light(coap_rw_buffer_t *scratch, const coap_packet_t *inpkt,coap_packet_t *outpkt, uint8_t id_hi, uint8_t id_lo)
{

 if (inpkt->payload.len == 0)
    return coap_make_response(scratch, outpkt, NULL, 0, id_hi, id_lo, COAP_RSPCODE_BAD_REQUEST, COAP_CONTENTTYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);

 if (inpkt->payload.p[0] == '1')
 {
    light = '1';


    UARTWrite(1,"ON\n");


    return coap_make_response(scratch, outpkt, (const UINT8_VAL *)&light, 1, id_hi, id_lo, COAP_RSPCODE_CHANGED, COAP_CONTENTTYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
 }
 else
 {
    light = '0';

    UARTWrite(1,"OFF\n");

    return coap_make_response(scratch, outpkt, (const UINT8_VAL *)&light, 1, id_hi, id_lo, COAP_RSPCODE_CHANGED, COAP_CONTENTTYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
 }
}
```

This is my code and i am getting error on line no.5 . The struct is defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    coap_header_t hdr;
    coap_buffer_t tok;
    uint8_t numopts;
    coap_option_t opts[MAXOPT];
    coap_buffer_t payload;
} coap_packet_t;

    typedef struct
{
    const UINT8_VAL *p;
    size_t len;
} coap_buffer_t;
```

I am getting the following error when i try to compile using Microchip c30 compiler which is primarily C compiler.

> Error :- error: invalid operands to binary ==

Please HElp me !!

Comment: Can you narrow it down to one of the two lines with `==`? Is `inpkt->payload.len` numeric? Is `one` numeric? You're sure you're even in the right file?

Comment: Seeing the definitions of `one` and `coap_buffer_t` would help.

Comment: `one` would seem to be the likely culprit. How is it defined?

Comment: @all : Thanks for the qucick reply. Actually let me make my question clear.

The error is in line no 5 [  if (inpkt->payload.p[0] == '1') ] where the compiler is throwing the error. I had actually changed the '1' to 'one' and still the error was there. The definitions of coap_buffer_t is also a typedef struct. I will post that too.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `coap_buffer_t`?

Comment: Done. POsted the definition of coap_buffer_t.

Comment: I suspect `1` is of type `signed char` in your compiler and it doesn't like using it with an `UINT8_VAL` in the `==` operator. Try using `if (inpkt->payload.p[0] == (UNIT8_VAL)'1')`

Comment: after changing the '1' to (UINT8_VAL)'1'; i am getting this error :
**error: cast to union type from type not present in union**

Comment: I suspect that `coap_buffer_t` wasn't available at the time of declaring `coap_packet_t`, hence it'll be assigned the default type of `int`. You need to move the declaration of `coap_buffer_t` to before  `coap_packet_t`

Comment: Based on that error message it seems `UINT8_VAL` is a union. Please show the definition of that. You will need to select one of the union members.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Actually it was defined before only. I moved it down when editing the question !!

Comment: @MattMcNabb : I am actually coding for open picus which uses Microchip C30 compiler. So the open picus framework is such that it has some inbuilt definitions. So we just have to use them. I have to search its files to get the union.

Comment: you're in a better position to search its files than I am ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Val` member of UINT8_VAL for comparison:

```
inpkt->payloadp[0].Val == '1'
```

Comment: Actually the above code i posted was a working code of arduino. I am trying to port it for open picus. So i am getting so many error of which half i dont understand what it means too since it is new to me !!

Comment: There is a definition of `coap_buffer_t` here: https://github.com/1248/microcoap/blob/master/coap.h that has a `uint8_t` p member. I think the original code you have assumes that.

Comment: Exactly that is the one i am using.. !! are u familiar with open picus ?

Comment: no, not really. but make sure you are including correct headers.